# How many ways can students be placed into classes

Tags: combinatorics

I am very new to combinatorics and want to know how many ways some number of pupils (`p`) can fit in some number of classes (`c`)  each of the same size (`s`).

I tried to solve it below using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496973/how-many-such-ways-to-group-2n-students) post:

---

Say we have 300 pupils that need to be separated into 10 classes of 30.

There are `300!` ways to line the students up.

Line all 300 students up and for each 30 students place them in a new class.
There are two ways to move students around and achieve the same set of classes:

(1) Move students around within each section of 30. One class can be rearranged in `30!` ways. As there are 10 classes, you must raise `30!` to 10. This means there is `30!^10` ways to rearrange the students within each class of 30.

(2) Swap entire groups of 30 around. There are 10 classes, so there is `10!` ways to do this.

Using both of those methods it means there are `30!^10 * 10!` combinations of lined up students that result in the same outcome of classes

This means I divide `300!` by `30!^10 * 10!`, which means the formula is `p! / (s!^c * c!)`. Obviously this is wrong.

---

Could someone please explain what I did wrong, what the correct way to do this is, and what the answer is please? All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: First, you need to get clear on this:  are the students distinguishable from each other?  And what about the rooms?  For example, if neither the students nor the rooms are distinguishable, then there is exactly one way to put the 300 students in 10 rooms of size 30.  Also ... why do you say "Obviously, this is wrong"?   How do you know? Are you supposed to get some formula at the end?

Comment: My initial assumption would have been that students are distinct, classes are distinct, and order within the classes is irrelevant.  This would be the multinomial coefficient $\binom{300}{30,30,30,\dots,30} = \dfrac{300!}{(30!)^{10}}$.  The answer of $\dfrac{p!}{(s!)^c\cdot c!}$ is the correct answer for if students were distinct, classes were indistinct, and order within the class is irrelevant.