# Why are there not $(n-1)! \over ({n \over 2})!$ permutations of $1$ through $n$ where $\forall i, \sigma(\sigma(i))=i$ and $\sigma(i) \neq i$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am seeing that the answer to the following problem should be just $(n-1)! \over ({(n \over 2})!$ and am wondering what conceptual errors I am making:

> How many permutations of 1 through $n$ are there such that for each $i, \sigma(\sigma(i))=i$ and $\sigma(i) \neq i$ ? (For example, the permutation 3,4,1,2 is such a permutation, since for example $\sigma(\sigma(1))=\sigma(3)=1$. You may assume $n$ is even.)
> **Answer**: $\frac{n !}{2^{n / 2}(n / 2) !}$. This is the number of ways to swap, so we can pick them out in pairs

I seeing that it is $(n-1)! \over ({n \over 2})!$ because there are $n-1$ ways to pick the first item in our permutation (we exclude this being $1$), which then determines what another item in our permutation  should be- but we could pick an item for an element not determined by this choice, for which we have $n-2$ choices: this again pre-determines another item of the permutation, but there still exists another item not predetermined, which we then pick having $n-3$ choices, etc. Eventually, when we have picked for half of the elements in our permutation of length $n$, so picked $n \over 2$ times, we would get an entire permutation. The possibilities explored here was $(n-1)! \over ({n \over 2})!$. Why is this wrong?

Comment: The two formulas already differ when $n=6$, so I suggest just writing out all the good permutations in that case.  the numbers are all quite small, so this is manageable.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496973/how-many-such-ways-to-group-2n-students)

Comment: Yes there are $n-1$ possibilities for the first item. Are you sure there are $n-2$ possibilities for the second item?